# Remove parenthesis that contain certain word - regex

Tags: php, regex

I am currently using regex to remove parentheses from strings. It works well and can even be applied on nested parentheses. However, there are certain times i dont want to remove a parentheses and its content. How can I only remove parentheses(and its contents) that contain the words `remove.` and keep the other parentheses?

```
$string = "ABC (test. blah blah) outside (remove. take out)";
echo preg_replace("/\(([^()]*+|(?R))*\)/","", $string);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
[(](?![^)]*?remove)([^)]+)[)]
```

And replace by `$1`.

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/yL1pB6/1)

Explaining:

```
[(]            # the initial '('
(?!            # don't match if in sequence is found:
    [^)]*?     # before the closing ')'
    remove     # the 'remove' text
)              # 
([^)]+)        # then, save/group everything till the closing ')'
[)]            # and the closing ')' itself
```

Hope it helps.

---

Or simply this:

```
[(](?=[^)]*?remove)([^)]+)[)]
```

To match those which have `remove` text. Looks the `=` instead `!`.

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/yL1pB6/2)

---

With `php` code, it should be:

```
$input = "ABC (test. blah blah) outside (remove. take out)";
ECHO preg_replace("/[(](?=[^)]*?remove)([^)]+)[)]/", "$1", $input);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "replace by `$1`" can you modify with php code? Thanks.

Comment: Perfect. Is there away two remove additional spaces? after the formatting it leaves double spaces

Comment: @MaryCoding. Yes, just add `\s?` in the end of the regex.